# code executing date 1st jan on 31st jan DateTime.Add

Tags: c#

I have this code for sending birthday reminder e-mail. It is executing fine for every date other than 1st jan of every year. The E-mail which is to be sent on 1st jan is actually sent on 31 jan even when in database it is 1 jan and also variable is reading it as 1 jan and not 31 jan.
Code is:

```
public void birthdayReminder(string month)
{
    try
    {

        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmdReminder;
        SqlDataReader userReminder;
        bool result = false;

        string todaydate = "";
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        todaydate = now.ToString("dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();

        cmdReminder = con.CreateCommand();
        cmdReminder.CommandText = "select staffid, staffmonth, staffdate from tbstaff where staffmonth='" + month + "' and staffdate='" + todaydate + "' and staffcurrstatus='Active'";
        userReminder = cmdReminder.ExecuteReader();
        //userReminder.Read();
        result = userReminder.HasRows;

        while (userReminder.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con1;
                con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString);
                con1.Open();

                SqlDataReader rdr;
                SqlCommand cmdRemUpd = con1.CreateCommand();
                cmdRemUpd.CommandText = "select * from tbl_BirthdayReminder where staffid='" + userReminder.GetInt32(0) + "' and year='" + DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() + "'";
                rdr = cmdRemUpd.ExecuteReader();

                bool res = rdr.HasRows;
                if(!res)
                    sendBirthdayEmail(userReminder.GetInt32(0));
                con1.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e1) { }
        }

        userReminder.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) { }
}

protected void sendBirthdayEmail(int id)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbstaff where staffid='" + id + "'", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString);
        adp.Fill(dt);

        string name=dt.Rows[0]["stafffname"].ToString()+' '+dt.Rows[0]["stafflname"].ToString();
        string acmng = dt.Rows[0]["staffacmng"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();

        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select emailAddress from tbuser where firstName='" + acmng + "'";
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();

        string to= dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
        con.Close();

        Configuration configurationFile = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~\\Web.config");
        MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSettings = configurationFile.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;

        string username = "";
        string password = "";
        string fromAddress = "";
        int port = 0;
        string host = "";

        if (mailSettings != null)
        {
            port = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Port;
            host = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host;
            password = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Password;
            username = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.UserName;
            fromAddress = username;
        }
        string Aliasname = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Alias"].ToString();

        string body = "";
        SmtpClient emailclient = new SmtpClient();
        string path = "http://www.columbuscorp.com/sat/images/happybirthday.jpg";
        body += "<html><body>";
        body += "Hello <br /><br />";
        body += "Please send birthday Card to " + name + " as his/her Birthday Date is on " + dt.Rows[0]["staffmonth"].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[0]["staffdate"].ToString() + "<br/>";
        body +="<img src=" + path;
        body += " width=672 height=491></img>";

        body += "<br /><br />Thanks from SAT Admin";
        body += "</body></html>";

        try
        {
            SqlConnection con1;
            con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString);
            con1.Open();

            SqlCommand cmdRemUpd = con1.CreateCommand();
            cmdRemUpd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_BirthdayReminder(staffid,year) values('" + id + "','" + DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() + "')";
            cmdRemUpd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con1.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e1) { }
```

Comment: Pro-tips: 1) DO NOT catch and swallow exceptions. Either handle them or let them go without catching. 2) Use the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to ensure resources like connections and data readers are closed correctly, even if there is an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date you are looking at is always one day in the future:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

That means on December 31st you are looking at a date in the next year. On the other hand this will use the "old" year, not the new one

```
cmdRemUpd.CommandText = "select * from tbl_BirthdayReminder where staffid='" + userReminder.GetInt32(0) + "' and year='" + DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() + "'";
```

So you are looking up a record that indeed does exist (last year's birthday reminder) hence the birthday reminder is not sent - it should be the same date as above I assume, so rather:

```
cmdRemUpd.CommandText = "select * from tbl_BirthdayReminder where staffid='" + userReminder.GetInt32(0) + "' and year='" + now.Year.ToString() + "'";
```

Comment: Yup, *bad* naming choice.  now == tomorrow.